# Show content of a file geodatabase on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I uploaded a zipped file geodatabase into ArcGIS Online from the content menu. Now I want to see the features inside my geodatabase displayed on the map and I can't find any option to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread on **[GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/89633)** that covers this process.

> Open the MXD in which you have prepared your gdb layer with your
>   symbology. Make sure only that layer is in your MXD.
>
> 1) Click on File -> Sign In... (Here you sign into your organizational
>   account)
>
> 2) Click on File -> Share As -> Service -> Publish a service
>
> 3) As connection choose My Hosted Services (My Account) and as service
>   name use what you want the layer to be called.
>
> 4) Under the capabilities tab uncheck "Tiled Mapping" and check
>   "Feature Access"
>
> 5) Fill out the Item Description tab
>
> 6) Under sharing you can check who is able to see it once published
>
> 7) Click Publish in the upper right corner and it will soon show up in
>   your "My Content" on ArcGIS Online
>
> Now you can use those feature services in your maps.
>
> You can do this for each file in you gdb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish this as a hosted feature layer with your organizational account that supports publishing.
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F878B830119B4443A8CFDA8A96AAF7D1